# Programming Beginner needs help understanding Recursion (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, recursion, constants

I'm learning JavaScript on freeCodeCamp.org and currently learning recursion.

I do know a bit how recursion works. It's basically a function calling itself.

Here is an example of recursion they provided:

```
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

This code just prints out an array starting from 1 to n.

Problem:
The line i'm confused with is: const countArray = countup(n - 1);

If the variable of 'countArray' is declared with 'const', how is it being re-assigned.

countArray is equal to the return value of the countup function.

Shouldn't you get an error for re-assigning a const variable?

If you pass in 5 as an argument to countup, eventually **n** will equal to 0, through recursion.

This will evaluate the boolean condition in the if statement to true. That will return an empty array, or more specifically return an empty array to countArray, since it's assigned the return value of the countup function.

So now we return to the callee function, where n is equal to 2 now. Plug in 2 for n, countup, is:
countup(1)

countArray is equal to an empty array. The following line of countArray.push(n): will push/add 1 to countArray.

So countArray is: countArray = [1];

Then add the final line, '[1]' get's returned to the callee function, which was countup(n - 1). Since we returned to the callee function, n is equal to 3. 3 - 1 is 2.

So countup now has an argument of 2: countup(2);

This is where I am confused.

What happens next?

Does it move onto the next line or does countup return 2 to countArray?

Since countArray was declared with **const, how is being re-assigned without any errors.

I ran the code, and no errors occurred.

I understood other examples of recursion, but for some reason I cannot understand this particular example.

Comment: It’s not re-assigned; each invocation of `countup` has a single assignment to `countArray`.

Comment: I’d recommend either “playing computer” with a pencil and paper and trace the execution line-by-line, or stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Think of it as having as many copies of a book as you need, each time you recurse, you put the current book down, stuff in a bookmark that says "come back to this" and then open a new copy of the same book. But: this subject has _loads_ of excellent tutorials on the web already, that's not SO's role. If you want to _learn_ programming, this is generally [the wrong place](/help/on-topic) to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> If the variable of 'countArray' is declared with 'const', how is it being re-assigned.

Each time a function is called, it creates its own set of local variables. These variables may have the same name as other variables, but they are new variables, scoped to just this one call of the function. This can happen when there are multiple functions, as in the following:

```
function a() {
  const myLocalVar = 'a';
  b();
}

function b() {
  const myLocalVar = 'b'; // No problem
}
a();
```

And while it's a bit harder to visualize, the same behavior happens when a single function calls itself recursively.

> If you pass in 5 as an argument to countup, eventually n will equal to 0, through recursion.
>
> This will evaluate the boolean condition in the if statement to true. That will return an empty array, or more specifically return an empty array to countArray, since it's assigned the return value of the countup function.
>
> So now we return to the callee function, where n is equal to 2 now.

Close, in the callee `n` is equal to 1. And it has just finished evaluating the right hand side of `const countArray = countup(n - 1);`. countup(n - 1) just returned an empty array, and so that empty array gets assigned to `countArray` in this instance of the function.

Then it moves to the next line and pushes 1 into the array. And after that, it returns the array which now looks like `[1]`.

At this point we unwind one level further, to the callee where `n` is equal to 2. It just received an array containing `1`, which it assigns to its own `countArray`. It pushes `2` into the array then returns it (it's now `[1, 2]`).

And so it continues, unwinding the stack. Each time does the same thing: assign the existing array to `countArray`, push a number, then return the now-slightly-longer array. After the final return, the array contains 1 to n.